# Cannot import custom class

Tags: java, maven

Im new to Java and have created a project with maven. I have two files: App.java and Robot.java. Both are in the same folder and belong to the package `com.mycompany.app`.

However I cannot use Robot.java in App.java. From what i've read, there's no need tom import because they belong to the same package. App.java looks like:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import processing.core.PApplet;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App extends PApplet{

    Robot[] robots;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        PApplet.main("App");
    }
}
```

and Robot.java:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Robot extends PApplet{

    public Robot(){


    }   

}
```

I compile with `mvn package`. But I end up with the error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] Robot robot = new Robot();
```

pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.processing/core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.processing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

How can i import Robot? Or do i need to compile differently?

Comment: Have you declared the package in Robot.java? Does not look like in the given Code.

Comment: I don't see the line from the error message in your code example.

Comment: I hadnt declared the package, that worked thanks